# Get XML saved as String in Mongo DB

Tags: xml, mongodb

I have some problem. I saved an xml as string in mongo db collection.

```
'request' : '<company><name>ABC</name><link href="abc.com">Website</link><person>Abi</person><person>Harry</person><person>Rasmus</person><person>Tamlyn</person><address street="yes"><street>Longford Street</street><city>London</city></address></company>'
```

But when I run the find query to get that xml,

```
$connection->selectDB(DB_NAME)->selectCollection(COLCTN_NAME)->find('request');
```

I get a string having the data between the xml tags, I dont get the complete xml with tags.

```
ABCWebsiteAbiHarryRasmusTamlynLongford StreetLondon
```

Please suggest how to get the complete xml with tags.

Comment: Did you check the same in mongodb shell also ?

Comment: i check it & giving the expected out put as you want

Comment: It seems, marshaling or unmarshaling issue. where are you running the query?